# Force matplotlib to use n ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've tried

```
plt.locator_params(tight=False, axis = 'y', nbins = 4)
```

and

```
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator( MaxNLocator(nbins = 4) )
```

but that only makes matplotlib use *up to 4* ticks, not exactly 4.

How can I force the y-axis to have exactly 4 ticks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10))
plt.yticks([0, 3, 6, 9])
```

[image]

To automatically adjust the tick locations to your data, you might want to use [`linspace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html):

```
import numpy as np
print np.linspace(0, 9, 4)
```

Output:

```
[ 0.  3.  6.  9.]
```